# Views form page with input fields

Tags: 7, views, forms

How can I make Views form page with such input fields?

[image: views input]
Such view can really help to change meanings of some node field all at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editable Views should do what you are trying to accomplish. It won't allow you to drag the items up/down, but it will allow you to update multiple fields at once.

https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews

> Editable Views lets you create Views where the fields can be edited. Fields show both the current value and a form to edit it. A 'Save' button allows saving of all the entities shown in the View.

Comment: There is conflict with [TVI](https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi) module. But I can handle it. Thanks